# .htaccess Rewrite Engine setting exemption to rule shared SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have multiple domains pointing to the same web space ie domain.com domain.co.uk ect...

and i use .htaccess to force all requests to domain.com, which works great however i need to use a shared SSL provided by my host which points to my web space on the server, and i access it using the shared ssl domain. ( http://shared_ssl.com/domain.co.uk  ).

The problem i have is .htaccess keep re-writing the domain to http://www.domain.com, when i try an access the shared ssl.

Is there a way to have an exception to the re-write rule?

here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite domain.org-> domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand your problem exactly, but this is how would do it:

```
  RewriteEngine on

  # Rewrite domain.org-> domain.com
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .                       # <- Not necessary

  # (you can have the whole shared_ssl.com if you want, but not necessary)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shared_ssl [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
  # (and this is the preferable way to write it - I think)
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```